# The Community user incorrectly has the staff label on all sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, user-card, user-labels

I've noticed that the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has a staff label on all sites now:

[image: Community [Staff] [Bot]]

It also shows on user links on meta sites:

[image: Community [Staff] [Bot] modified 7 hours ago]

However, this is incorrect: the Community user is *not* a staff member. It is not a human user who works for Stack Exchange; it is an automated process.

This just started happening today: previously, the Staff label wasn't visible on any site. I think it was because the Community user was just granted staff rights, and there's no check for negative user IDs when determining whether to display the label. Can it please be removed?

Comment: Might be on purpose, part of a big change of scope of the staff label.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if Teams had anything to do with it

Comment: ... I don't see a staff label... :shifty:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically, the Community user didn't have an associated network account. That recently changed and the account was created with a `Developer` account type. We have since demoted it to a regular user to minimize the odds of Community getting extra privileged site access in case of a robot uprising, so the staff label will no longer appear on the profile.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: It's not very nice of us, firing the community user so shortly before the holidays 

Comment: @balpha layoffs reached the bots...

Comment: @balpha I think it was necessary - wouldn't want to give ChatGPT any delusions of future employment here.