# Talking to the Community user

Tags: discussion, community-user

Is it possible to talk to the Community user? If not, why? So you may know it's a bot that sometimes bumps old unanswered questions, owns community votes, own downvotes on permanently deleted questions, and deletes abandoned questions. But can you talk to it? If not, why?

Comment: Related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161544/608272

Comment: It's an exceptionally good listener. :b

Comment: This was [tried a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238453/377214) and disabled because it got out of hand.

Comment: "But can you talk to it?" - **what exactly do you imagine this would involve**? One does not normally "talk to" even other human users of the site, the way that I understand "talk to".

Comment: The community user very  much exists so actions could be attributed to *someone* should the user account be deleted or something else happened. I vaguely recall in the early days that spammers got merged into it too.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. As for whether the bot will react, that is another matter.

Comment: @Sonic it got nothing to do about chat. Question is about the community **user**, not the chatbot. Either way the question is utterly unclear, and can't really be salvaged, so not very relevant.

Comment: It’s not a bot. It’s a user that is used to submit automatically generated comments on the behalf of reviewers who were being attacked when those same automated comments were automatically being submitted on their behalf. ChatGPT chatbots are dumb, it would be a waste of money, to develop one.

Comment: @Ramhound while I agree that it's a mistake to call or label it a "bot", it's also far from being a "user". User implies there is a person (single person) behind it, and that's just not the case with Community user. It's more like a "dummy account" created to be used in various ways, not only review which you mentioned. Part of this is listed in the profile.

Comment: I certainly described it as a user who only does things on behalf of users automatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of January 16th, 2024, [Community [Bot]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) is a "dumb bot"; it's not a *[chatbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot)*, it's not an AI either, it's a "background process". The "Community [Bot]" user display name is used instead of the user display name belonging to an [end-user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_user).

Please note that the *user profile* and the *user card* for this "bot" show the `[Bot]` label/tag.

[image: Snip of the Community [Bot] user profile]

From the *Community [Bot]*'s user profile (taken on January 15th, 2024):

> #### About
>
> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - Remove abandoned questions

Due to the notability that *[chatbots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot)* took after the launch of **[ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT)** in November 2022, you might be expecting to be able to interact with it as it's possible to do with *bots* powered by ChatGPT API or like. Considering this, you might be interested in learning about *OverflowAI*, the brand used by Stack Exchange, Inc., "marketed" as *Stack Overflow*, since the summer of 2023 to talk about the AI things they are doing with AI/Gen AI. They have a microsite about this https://stackoverflow.co/labs.

### Related

**Featured (FAQ)**

- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/289691)

**Other**

- [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/289691)
- [The Community user incorrectly has the staff label on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384475/289691)

**Announcements**

- Blog article : [Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/)

**Wikipedia**

- [Stack Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange)

Comment: Related: *[Eggs McLaren](http://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren)*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum how is this related here?